# Resetting Private Messages data

Tags: messages

Is there a painless way to reset messages their related data?

What I mean is to delete everything and clean up data and start with a clean slate, somewhat like what `TRUNCATE` does to a MySQL table.

The reason I want to do this is to remove some bad data deliberately injected because of  testing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clean up message data, you will need to TRUNCATE following database tables:

```
exp_message_attachments
exp_message_copies
exp_message_data
```

You can run following SQLs:

```
TRUNCATE exp_message_attachments;
TRUNCATE exp_message_copies;
TRUNCATE exp_message_data;
```

Also, EE stores number of private messages within exp_members database table (column private_messages). So you will need to run this SQL:

```
UPDATE exp_members SET private_messages = 0
```

Please take a backup of database to avoid any other data problem.

**Note**: Anyone can see my same answer [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237439/) also.